# Como realizar TDD utilizando Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tdd

Gostaria de saber como realizar o TDD usando [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/). Me informaram que este ORM armazena memória antes de gravar no possível, então queria saber como testar um dado que está em memória. Por exemplo: executo o comando para salvar e faço um teste para verificar se este dado esta salvo, é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que entender o seguinte, o cache está atrelado ao PersistenceContext que é criado quando você cria um EntityManager.

Você pode usar sem problemas o JUnit com EntityManager para testar seu DAO. O que você deve fazer é:

1. Adicionar o HSQLDB como dependência ou algum outro banco em memória
2. Ter um persistence.xml somente para o teste, nesse caso, bastaria adicioná-lo dentro de um diretório test, no caso do maven, que automaticamente essa troca de contexto seria feita.
3. Crie um EntityManagerFactory estático:

   private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
4. Criar um método estático anotado com @BeforeClass que criará o EntityManagerFactory:

   @BeforeClass
   public static void createPersistenceUnit() {
       entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU")
   }
5. Crie um método estático anotado com @AfterClass para matar o EntityManagerFactory:

   @AfterClass
   public static void closePersistenceUnit() {
       entityManagerFactory.close();
   }
6. Crie um método anotado com @Before para iniciar o EntityManager a cada teste:

   @Before
   public void beforeTest() {
       entityManager = getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
   }
7. Crie um método com @After para finalizar o EntityManager após cada teste:

   @After
   public void finishTest() {
       entityManager.close();
   }

Desse modo você vai ter um EntityManager para cada teste e seu cache de primeiro nível não será problema.

Esse post é meio velhinho, mas fala sobre isso: http://uaihebert.com/tdd-com-hsqldb-jpa-e-hibernate/

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível utilizar somente o cache de primeiro nível do Hibernate para utilizar em casos de testes. A melhor abordagem para esse problema é configurar o Hibernate para que ele use algum banco de dados em memória.

Alguns banco de dados em memória que você pode utilizar são: HSQLDB, o Apache Derby ou o H2DB.

Basta criar um `DataSource` para algum destes BDs e utiliza-lo na configuração do Hibernate utilizada nos seus casos de testes.

Exemplo: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/HibernateandHSQL.htm

Comment: Esta é a estratégia adequada para a maioria das situações.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que vocês esta indo pelo caminho de testar a tecnologia e não o domínio do negócio de seu problema.

Acho que você poderia tentar "mockar" o hibernate com um mockito por exemplo e não se preocupar tanto com a tecnologia e sim com as regras de negócio, afinal é pra isso que usamos o TDD... :-)

Comment: Pois é, mas eu queria salvar em objeto e testar uma validação do tipo, se aquele objeto já existe no banco. Mais para testar o método.

Comment: Assim você continua testando a tecnologia, a não ser que a regra de negócio é relacionada a ter o objeto em memória ou não...

Pode ser que "mockar" o método que retorna o objeto da memória, lhe ajude a testar os outros métodos de negócio, dá uma olhadinha no mockito, pode ajudar alguns exemplos dele...

Comment: A regra seria tipo, se o objeto já existe quando consultado ao BD, ele não insere, coisas deste tipo.

Comment: Me parece algo como um update. Mas se não for este o caso, então poderia ser algo para um cache fora do hibernate... talvez...